# Installing Fedora and preserving Grub

Tags: installation, fedora, grub

I installed Fedora 24 3 times last year.

Each times, Fedora ended up overwriting previous Grub with its own **without asking**. I don't even know during which part of the installation it did that.

This was not supposed to create any problems, but on a multiple boot including a Windows installed with the UEFI (I didn't want that…), I wasn't able to access my Windows at all after that.

I want to install Fedora 25 but I want to be sure it will not reinstall its own Grub.

Can I have tips to avoid that?

Comment: I had a very different experience. In the past 6 months, I've installed Fedora 24 and Fedora 25 on two separate Windows 10 laptops (both dual-boot now ).  And while each Fedora install created a grub boot menu, etc., the Windows bootloader was listed as a boot option for each... and it works.

Comment: You may find the Fedora Installation Document helpful, especially section 5.4.8.1. Boot Loader Installation . https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning.html

Comment: I tried on different laptops with the same configuration. Others tried too. Same result. I'll try again while reading the documentation, thank you for the link (didn't found even after numerous researchs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @rickhg12hs, I found the installation documentation here:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning.html

During partitionning, there's a link at the bottom of the page I didn't notice a single time, just here (on an old Fedora installer, not mine):
[image: Bootloader configuration]

I disabled the installation of the bootloader on my disk and everything went well.

The only reproach I can make is the link not really obvious even after reading steps explained in the documentation.